# Does Django requery every time I access a related model?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model that has a foreign key like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

and I have a method on Foo that defines a dictionary with the following:

```
{'bar_mode': self.bar.mode,
'bar_name': self.bar.name}
```

If I'm using MySQL as my backend, will this result in two separate queries to the Bar table? Or will Django, having retrieved Bar from the database, be smart enough (i.e., have some simple short term caching implemented) to only query Bar once and use the previous results? If not, is the easiest solution simply to store self.bar in a variable and use that variable throughout the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once you have accessed it the first time, the related entity will be cached and subsequent lookups will not hit the db again.

Note though that this is a per-object cache: if for any reason you re-fetch the Foo instance, the cache will be lost and a call to bar will cause another query.

Also note that you can eliminate the extra call altogether by using `select_related` when you query Foo in the first place.